# How can you read that messages that are shown during boot before X starts?

Tags: boot, log

I edited in my `/etc/default/grub`, the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet
```

After that, `sudo update-grub`, and it now shows me the messages during boot.

but how can I read that messages after X is started?

```
/var/log/boot.log
```

doesn't contain what I see there for a blink of an eye.

Comment: What about `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: That is the question! I can see all logs filled during boottime for example at "Mar 31 14:12" with `find /var/log/ -type f -name "*log" -exec grep -H "Mar 31 14:12" {} \;` but that is much more than I saw during boot before X started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output at boot is logged in:

```
/var/log/kern.log
```